# Converting logback.xml to log4j2.xml configuration

Tags: logging, migration, log4j2, logback

I'm trying to convert my logback.xml configuration into log4j2.xml however I'm having some issues so I was hoping that someone could share tool or some good / detailed article with instructions on how to do that. I was searching a lot for that information but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: if you want to post your logback.xml, we maybe able to help. The alternative is the Apache website. There is no tools other than the notepad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find tool for converting *logback.xml* into *log4j2.xml* but since my task was to translate *log4j.properties* into *log4j2.xml* I found a tool which can translate *log4j.properties* into *logback.xml* and that tool is:

https://logback.qos.ch/translator/

However if you're interested in converting *log4j.properties* into *log4j2.xml* you can take a look at example I provided here:

[Converting log4j.properties into log4j2.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71396034/converting-log4j-properties-into-log4j2-xml/71500519#71500519)